# python stdout function returns none on last line

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I have a bunch of lines in an input text file:

```
field1;field2;...fieldn
```

that I what to convert to an output.json whose lines are:

```
{field_name1:field1,field_name2:field2,...field_namen:fieldn}
```

So what I did is, using the following code:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
import json

def txt_to_json(*args):
        for line in stdin:
                fields = [x.strip() for x in line.split(";")]
                stdout.write(json.dumps(dict(zip(args, fields))) + "\n")
```

in a shell (if input.txt contains three fields):

```
python -c "from process_files import *; print txt_to_json('field_name1','field_name2','field_name3')" < input.txt  > output.json
```

My output is fine except it contains None on the last line. I tried to modify my function but cannot get rid of this last None.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does return `None`, you are printing the result of the function which then is piped to the file, remove the `print()` call:

```
python -c "from process_files import *; txt_to_json('field_name1','field_name2','field_name3')" < input.txt  > output.json
```